# How do I target a links only in a custom post type and only in the p tag?

Tags: custom-post-types, css

https://airprofan.com/industrial-fan-applications/abrasive-airstream/

This is a page under a custom post type for applications (https://airprofan.com/industrial-fan-applications).

We want every hyperlinked text to be underlined, but only in the paragraphs, not in the ul's.

So on the example page I gave, I'm looking for each of these to underline: https://cl.ly/ogil.

Of course we could do it all manually, but there has to be a way through CSS to do this. We have 30 of these pages now and always are tweaking.

Comment: on the body element you have the CSS class `single-application` that you can use to target pages of this custom post type.

Comment: I've messed around with that a bit but haven't been able to get it...surely a lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this-

```
.single-application .entry-content p > a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Where `.single-application` is based on your post type, `.entry-content` is the wrapper of your post content.

See the page source-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and fix, it worked as expected.